realm swift takes too much time to deleteAll(). i generally have around 6k-7k Objects to be deleted using deleteAll
I'm using Realm Swift in my iOS application, and I'm facing performance issues when trying to delete a large number of objects from the database. Specifically, I have around 6,000 to 7,000 objects that I need to delete at once using the deleteAll() method, but it seems to take a significant amount of time to complete the operation.
Is there a way to track the progress of the deletion process? It would be helpful to provide feedback to users while the deletion is in progress, such as showing a progress indicator.
    func clearAllRealmData() {
        if let realm = try? Realm() {
            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.deleteAll()
                }
                realm.refresh()
            } catch {
                print("Error clearing data from Realm: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }


I think there's something else wrong and/or affecting your results. I crafted a small app that writes 8000 objects to Realm. Then there's a button to click that runs your exact code. I capture the current time before starting the delete, and then after it's done; that gives me the elapsed time. Here's the output to console delete all -  elapsed time of 0.0039060115814208984. So it takes .003 seconds to delete 8000 objects. I ran the same test using realm.write as well as realm.asyncWrite. I also did it with 50,000 objects and the elapsed time was just slightly longer.

Thanks it means a lot @jay actually what i have identified my mistake
